# How to use MAX() and COUNT() in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have the following table:

> transactions(id, type)
>
> `id` - id of the costumer (integer 1...n)
>  `type` - what they
>   bought (like "apple")

Note that each row refers to buying only ONE of the given type.

How can I select the id of the costumer who bought the most of a given type (like apple)?

I tried to `COUNT()` the rows where type = apple for each id, but I cannot use `MAX()` in that query to select only the first ID.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first make a query that for every customer counts the amount of times he bought an `'apple'`, with:

```
SELECT id,COUNT(*) AS total
FROM transactions
WHERE type = 'apple'
GROUP BY id
```

Now we only need to `ORDER BY` that `total` in `DESC`ending order, and return the [first row with `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html), like:

```
SELECT id,COUNT(*) AS total
FROM transactions
WHERE type = 'apple'
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY total DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL 101, you should read about `group by` clause:

```
select id,
    count(*) as count_of_apples
from transactions
where type = 'apple'
group by id
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking for Oracle in particular: `STATS_MODE` gives you the value that occurs most often.

```
select stats_mode(id)
from transactions
where type = 'apple';
```